# Specifying the content of a HttpRequestMessage for a Web API unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api

I have a web API controller method I want to unit test. It takes in a `HttpRequestMessage` but I can't work out how to set the content that I want to pass in. Is it possible to create/mock the `HttpRequestMessage` so that I can give it a `string` that I want to be the result of `await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()`?

This is my controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    var data = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    //do something with data
}
```

I can easily create the `HttpRequestMessage` with its parameterless constructor, but I can't work out how to set the content to a meaningful value. I would like my test to work along these lines:

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task PostMethodWorks()
{
    var controller = new MyController();

    var data = "this will be JSON";
    var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage();
    //set the content somehow so that httpRequestMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync returns data

    var response = await controller.Post(httpRequestMessage);

    //assert something about the response here
}
```

Is it possible to set the value of the content to some JSON, or will I need to change the method so it takes in a different parameter?

(For more context, the reason I want to have the method taking in a `HttpRequestMessage` is because I'm working on a legacy codebase with that has loads of controller methods which take in a `HttpRequestMessage`.)

Comment: This feels like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) as ideally Web API actions don't take `HttpRequestMessage` as a argument. WHat are you doing with the string once you extract it from the request?

Comment: I've done some digging into why the legacy code is written like this. It seems most of our client side code is using `jQuery.post` which encodes data as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. If the controller method takes a `HttpRequestMessage` it can understand serialised data regardless of the encoding, but if the method takes in a DTO the encoding must be correct (i.e. `application/json` if serialised). This means that changing the jQuery settings to use JSON encoding by default will be a breaking change for the methods which take a DTO (and are being passed non-serialised data).

Comment: Essentially the reason for the odd use of a `HttpRequestMessage` as a controller method parameter is because we haven't been properly encoding the data we're posting, but now that there's a mix of approaches it's a pain to standardise them.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Is it possible to set the value of the content to some JSON

**Yes**

You can use any one of the many [`HttpContent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpcontent?view=netframework-4.7.2) derived classes. Since in this case you want to send JSON content, you would want to use [`StringContent class`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.stringcontent?view=netframework-4.7.2)

For example

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task PostMethodWorks() {
    //Arrange
    var controller = new MyController();

    var data = "this will be JSON";
    var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage();

    //set the content somehow so that httpRequestMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync returns data 
    httpRequestMessage.Content = new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");


    //Act
    var response = await controller.Post(httpRequestMessage);

    //Assert
    //assert something about the response here
}
```

This however feels like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) as ideally Web API actions don't take `HttpRequestMessage` as a argument.

> or will I need to change the method so it takes in a different parameter?

Model binders exist that can be used to have strongly typed action parameters that will parse the incoming data and populate the models before passing then to the actions.